# How can I selecting JSON File In AppleScript when they appear grayed out in the open dialog?

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

I am trying to select a json file but its always grayed out

```
set json to (POSIX path of (choose file of type {"json"} with prompt "Select a .json file."))
display dialog json as text
```

Can anyone help me past this block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This small edit works for me.

```
set json to (POSIX path of (choose file of type "public.json" with prompt "Select a .json file."))
display dialog json as text
```

**NOTE:**  *This following code is what I used to get the value of what to use for the `of type` in the `choose file` command, for the code above.*

```
activate
set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Choose File To ID its Type") as text

tell application "System Events" to set fileType to type identifier of file theFile
```

In this following image, the description for the `of type` parameter for the `choose file` command says you can use "file types" or "type identifiers".

Since `choose file of type {"json"}` doesn't work, the only other option was to get the "type identifier" for .json files and use that instead.  System Events gets the value for the "type identifier" of files.

[image]

Comment: Adding public.json has in fact worked. May I ask how you knew to put public. before the extensnion name and also do you know why json on its own didn't work.

Comment: @IanBarber check the edits I added to my original post.  Sometimes the process of writing code involves a whole bunch of trial and error combined with deductive reasoning.  Sometimes it's just good old fashioned "stubbornness" as to not give up until you figure it out.

Comment: Nice answer with good, clear explanations.  +1

Comment: @CJK I must be doing something right if all you could find wrong with my post was one misplaced apostrophe LOL.  It's good to see you are still lurking and occasionally offer your "2 cents".  I have learned so much from your posts… I always welcome your critiques.

Comment: Thanks, @wch1zpink.  That's very gracious of you.